# Why do scripts ran via "sh *.sh" function differently than "./*.sh"?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. I have noticed a weird problem.

When running a `rsync` command embedded in a shell script (as root) with `--exclude={}` options, `rsync` works and excludes paths as it's supposed to when I launch it as root via

```
./rBackup.sh
```

However, when I run it as root via

```
sh rBackup.sh
```

the exclude directory options do not carry over, and it infinite loops when backing up the drive it's backing up to in `/media/`. Why?

Edit - this is not a sh / bash difference - or shouldn't be. I have #!/bin/bash as the first line, so when running via "sh *.sh" it should use the bash interpreter - at least, in theory.

Script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

StandbyMount="/media/astump/sdb2"
mount /dev/sdb2 $StandbyMount
rsync -aAXv --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found,/etc/fstab,/boot/grub/grub.cfg} --delete-before / $StandbyMount
umount $StandbyMount
rm -fr $StandbyMount
```

Comment: Because sh calls dash, debian amquist shell, and those curly braces are probably interpreted as inputs to dash, not a standalone command

Comment: Edited the question to clarify. I do have #!/bin/bash as the first line, so in theory at least, it should use bash even when calling it via "sh *.sh"

Comment: @user3260912 doesn't matter if you have the `#!/bin/bash` there. If you call script with `sh script.sh` it will run with `sh`.

Answer (score 5):

When you run

```
sh rBackup.sh
```

the script `rBackup.sh` is being run by `sh` (`dash`) which does not support brace expansion.

On the other hand, when you do

```
./rBackup.sh
```

then the `#!/bin/bash` first line specifies the exact interpreter to use. It happens that `bash` supports brace expansion.

If you don't include a valid executable in the shebang line, you are simply running the script under the current shell you are in (or `sh` depending on the shell implementations).

**Example:** From `bash`:

```
$ cat scr.sh 
echo {bar,spam}

$ sh scr.sh 
{bar,spam}

$ ./scr.sh 
bar spam
```

My login shell is `zsh`. Here are some points to note:

- While at `zsh`, `./scr.sh` is being sent to `sh`(`dash`)
- While at `bash`, `./scr.sh` is being sent to `bash`
- While at `ksh`, `./scr.sh` is being sent to `ksh`
- While at `dash`, `./scr.sh` is being sent to `sh` (`dash`)

---

To be on the safer side always try to mention the desired interpreter using shebang (first line of the script) e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: If the shebang isn't valid, the `/bin/sh` will be used. See [`man 3 exec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/exec.3.html) (**Special semantics for execlp() and execvp()**):        *If the header of a  file  isn't  recognized  (the  attempted  execve(2)
       failed  with the error ENOEXEC), these functions will execute the shell
       (/bin/sh) with the path of the file as its first  argument.*

Comment: @muru I don't see its happening apart from `zsh` (and dash`)..what gives?

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that `sh` actually calls `dash`, which is limited compared to, say, Bash.

As was observed by [@Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg) in [a comment on the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731634/why-do-scripts-ran-via-sh-sh-function-differently-than-sh/731637#comment1085862_731634), the curly braces are being interpreted as inputs to dash, possibly, which is why it won't work.  This is why it's failing - Dash doesn't do Brace Expansion.

You're probably expecting the system to use Bash style interpretation.  If you are using a default shell of `bash` then executing the script with `./rBackup.sh` will, I believe, execute it in that running shell.

---

I think you're expecting that this script will be processed by Bash, which won't work when you do `sh`.

So let's do a couple things differently here:

(1) Define `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning, to make it use Bash when executed directly.

(2) `chmod +x rBackup.sh` - This will set the executable bit

(3) Execute the command ***only*** with `./rBackup.sh` or `bash ./rBackup.sh` or `bash rBackup.sh`.  This will ensure Bash is used to interpret the function in all cases; since it defines to use `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the file if you did step 1, it will try and use Bash when executing the script.